# ios:onclick tableviewcell if nsuserdefaults exists goto view controller else goto to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi friends am new in iphone apps developing in my project, am using `storyboards` I have a task where I need to authenticate for loading `viewController` on clicking from `tableViewCell`. I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` and I created a `segue` from that cell to `viewController`.

Now the problem is i need to authenticate the controller while clicking cell. if the user has not logged in it should goto login controller, else it it should go to activity controller. I have saved user details in `NSUserDefaults`. but I don't know how to authenticate it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`on `UITableViewCell`

here is the code for my configuring cell:

```
else if(indexPath.row == 4) {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier4 =@"MenuDetails4";
    activismCell *cell4 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier4 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell4.imgactivism.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon5.png"];
    cell4.activism.text = localize(@"some.activism");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if([defaults objectForKey:@"firstname"]!=NULL  && [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"]!=NULL) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto" id:indexpath];
    }

else if ([defaults objectForKey:@"firstname"] ==NULL  && [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"]==NULL) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" id:indexpath];
}
    return cell4;
```

On clicking that particular tableViewCell if user already logged in it should goto `activity ViewController` else it it should goto login view controller.

Please help me how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have the code for checking names in the cellForRowAtIndexPath ? might be easier to have a BOOL in NSUserDefaults to say that user has logged in instead of checking for a name.

Comment: why don't you check the condition in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't perform the segue in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to put this code in the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([defaults objectForKey:@"firstname"]!=NULL  && [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"]!=NULL){
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto" id:indexpath];
}
else if ([defaults objectForKey:@"firstname"] ==NULL  && [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"]==NULL) {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" id:indexpath];
}
}
```

in this method you can check the nsuserdefaults and then perform the segue accordingly.

Comment: Just take the code out of cellforrowsatindexpath and add it to didselectrowatindexpath like in my edit above.

Comment: its not working i have eight cells subclassed. among which only rows 4,5 and 6 to be aunthenticated.

Comment: Check the indexPath. If you only have 1 section. Then check indexPath.row

Comment: If you have your segue dragged from the cell to the destination view controller. Then delete it and add it again from the source view controller to the destination view controller. Don't forget to give the identifier to the segue.

Comment: u mean like this [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goto" id:indexpath.row];

Comment: I mean: if(indexPath.row == 4 || indexPath.row == 5 || indexPath.row == 6){ [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login"] }

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to move after selection a specific row.Then you need to implement this method of tableView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
           //You can apply your logic of selected row.

            ViewControllerName *VC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerName"];
            aboutUsVC.strQuote=[quoteArry objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];

              //This one for presenting the viewController modally
            //[self presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks